# How can I accept the Microsoft EULA agreement for ttf-mscorefonts-installer?

Tags: apt, software-installation, fonts, microsoft, license

After a recent update, `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` prompted me to accept its license agreement.

```
 ┌─────────────────┤ Configuring ttf-mscorefonts-installer ├─────────────────┐
 │                                                                           │ 
 │ TrueType core fonts for the Web EULA                                        
 │                                                                             
 │ END-USER LICENSE AGREEMENT FOR MICROSOFT SOFTWARE                           
 │                                                                             
 │ IMPORTANT-READ CAREFULLY: This Microsoft End-User License Agreement         
 │ ("EULA") is a legal agreement between you (either an individual or a        
 │ single entity) and Microsoft Corporation for the Microsoft software         
 │ accompanying this EULA, which includes computer software and may include    
 │ associated media, printed materials, and "on-line" or electronic            
 │ documentation ("SOFTWARE PRODUCT" or "SOFTWARE"). By exercising your        
 │ rights to make and use copies of the SOFTWARE PRODUCT, you agree to be      
 │ bound by the terms of this EULA. If you do not agree to the terms of        
 │ this EULA, you may not use the SOFTWARE PRODUCT.                            
 │                                                                             
 │                                  <Ok>                                       
 │                                                                           │ 
 └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Screenshot:
[image]

For some reason my terminal will not allow me to accept, or for some reason I am pressing the wrong hotkey...  I've tried every letter on the keyboard and <kbd>Enter</kbd> among others...  I'm sure there is a very simple and obvious solution to this.

Answer (score 542, accepted):

It's  <kbd>⇆ TAB</kbd> , then <kbd>return ↵</kbd>.

:-)

---

**In general, to navigate [`ncurses`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses)-style menus:**

- Use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to move from one element (e.g., button, text box) to the next. Use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to move in reverse.
- Use <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> to "click" the selected button.
- Use <kbd>Enter</kbd> to click the default button (or currently selected button, if there is no default).
- You can move up and down in a textbox with the arrow keys, and with <kbd>Page Up</kbd> and <kbd>Page Down</kbd>. If that doesn't work, press <kbd>Tab</kbd> until the text box you want to navigate in is selected.

**If you've accidentally said you don't agree to the EULA**, and you want a chance to review it again and agree, you can reinstall `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`, purging its global configuration files:

```
sudo apt-get --purge --reinstall install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

Comment: Personally, I think curses is wrong, you should be able to just press return. :P

Comment: Wow, I would have never figured that out. Does this only happen with Microsoft installers?

Comment: @BSeven: I guess Microsoft did not do the packaging on this one and the maintainer of the package implemented that dialog. But most of the time you don't have to accept EULAs when installing packages, so ...

Comment: I thought I'm the only person facing this, andI'm the only stupid to have not figured this out.. but it seems 121 users have upvoted the question and 161 liked as of date, I'm not the only one. you saved many of us. thnx

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved my problem. I couldn't find how to retrive this other way:)

Comment: I killed apt-get because I couldn't figure out how to accept the EULA. Now I'm stuck in a mess. Why the heck wasn't it something more obvious?

Comment: @StefanoPalazzo Well, windows works that way too, actually. As do many UI's in linux distros. Tab moves between fields and space or enter pushes buttons/toggles checkboxes/radio buttons. shift-tab goes backwards if you miss a field, btw. (the more you know)

Comment: And what if this doesn't work?

Comment: i think including the agreement in general is unnecessary, just more microsoft legal nonsense

Comment: "Well I'm probably stupid but let's try Google... Oh it auto-completed! So there are at least a few people searching..." (Sees 300 upvotes) "Ok I'm normal!"

Answer (score 131):

### Normal install, deploying or in scripts

Use debconf to preset the selection. This will not prompt to accept the license:

```
echo ttf-mscorefonts-installer msttcorefonts/accepted-mscorefonts-eula select true | sudo debconf-set-selections
sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

### With Kickstart

Add  this to your Kickstart.cfg file:

```
preseed --owner ttf-mscorefonts-installer msttcorefonts/accepted-mscorefonts-eula boolean true
```

Comment: When using `--quiet`, will it automatically accept the licence?

Comment: I needed two debconf entries: `echo ttf-mscorefonts-installer msttcorefonts/accepted-mscorefonts-eula select true | sudo debconf-set-selections` and `echo ttf-mscorefonts-installer msttcorefonts/present-mscorefonts-eula note | sudo debconf-set-selections`

Comment: @king_julien: no, `--quiet` will not accept the license, so that should not be an option without `echo ttf-mscorefonts-installer msttcorefonts/accepted-mscorefonts-eula select true | sudo debconf-set-selections`!

Comment: I removed the command without sudo and non-working `--quiet` option. Feel free to revert the edit if this is too much change, but I think the answer is much clearer like this now

Comment: how did you come up with the syntax for that? that's the interesting part. I want to apply this to `Java jdk`, `steamcmd`, ect

Comment: As of Ubuntu 19.04, this does not suppress the EULA display. It just makes the “Yes” pre-selected.

Comment: You sir, are a king among men.

Comment: Thank you - this was the only approach that worked for me in Docker.
    && echo "ttf-mscorefonts-installer msttcorefonts/accepted-mscorefonts-eula select true" | debconf-set-selections \
    && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends ttf-mscorefonts-installer \

Answer (score 21):

You can also accept the license with a single command like this:

```
echo ttf-mscorefonts-installer msttcorefonts/accepted-mscorefonts-eula select true | debconf-set-selections
```

This will avoid creating the conf file.

If your using puppet, here is a recipe for installing the package:

```
class unifocus-context::msfonts {
  exec { "accept-msttcorefonts-license":
    command => "/bin/sh -c \"echo ttf-mscorefonts-installer msttcorefonts/accepted-     mscorefonts-eula select true | debconf-set-selections\""
  }

  package { "msttcorefonts":
    ensure  => installed,
    require => Exec['accept-msttcorefonts-license']
  }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

*Some people may find this question when searching for help installing `ubuntu-restricted-extras` (or when their questions accepting a EULA for `ubuntu-restricted-extras` are closed as a duplicate of this question).*

[`ubuntu-restricted-extras`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/ubuntu-restricted-extras) is a [metapackage](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages) that exists solely to install other packages.

One of those packages is [`ttf-mscorefonts-installer`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/ttf-mscorefonts-installer). That's the one you must agree to a EULA to finish installing. It fetches Microsoft fonts and installs them on your system.

- To agree to the EULA, use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to switch from "button" to "button" in the non-graphical "window", and either the <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> ("clicks" the selected "button") or the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key ("clicks" the "default" button). You can move up and down in the EULA with the arrow keys and with <kbd>Page Up</kbd> and <kbd>Page Down</kbd>.
- If you've accidentally said you don't agree to the EULA, and you want a chance to review it again and agree, you can reinstall `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`, purging its global configuration files:

  ```
  sudo apt-get --purge --reinstall install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
  ```
- If you decide you don't want those fonts at all (or are unwilling to accept the EULA for them), but you do want the other packages provided by `ubuntu-restricted-extras`, then remove `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` and make sure you have the other packages and that they're set to manually installed (so they don't go away in an `autoremove` after `ubuntu-restricted-extras` is removed with `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`):

  ```
  sudo apt-get remove ttf-mscorefonts-installer
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-addons gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse libavcodec-extra-53 unrar
  ```

Comment: Is it possible to install the `ubuntu-restricted-extras` and automatically accept the licence in one command?

Answer (score 11):

Try hitting <kbd>➜</kbd> (The right arrow key). Then use the arrow keys to navigate and enter (That's return) for selecting an option.

Comment: Well the enter(return) key didn't work. Also the right arrow cannot be used for navigation either.

Comment: Brilliantly simple answer thats just saved me a lot of pain