# LibreOffice missing certain Microsoft fonts

Tags: fonts, libreoffice

I don't have these fonts:  times new roman, arial and calibri..., like in microsoft office? What can I do?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you just installed the fonts?  In that case, you need to restart libreoffice (and the quickstarter if it's running).

Comment: I believe the 'C' fonts (cambria, calibri, etc.) are not freely distributable like the old microsoft core fonts, and therefore impossible to include as a package in ubuntu repositories.

Answer (score 26):

I just typed in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

Comment: It's just as easy to open apt://ttf-mscorefonts-installer in your webbrowser. :)

Comment: This does work for the old windows fonts (Comic...), but not for calibri. For calibir, http://www.oooninja.com/2008/01/calibri-linux-vista-fonts-download.html works.

Comment: if the ttf-mscorefonts-installer package installs successfully but fails to actually download the fonts, install the package from debian sid instead: packages.debian.org/en/sid/all/ttf-mscorefonts-installer/… (this is a known bug: bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/msttcorefonts/+bug/1767748 )

Comment: How do I click OK in the dos-like window (EULA)?

Comment: @GuyCohen If you do it in a terminal you can use `<TAB>` (to switch option) and `<ENTER>` (to select an option).

Answer (score 15):

In case you are unable to install package "Microsoft Core Fonts" (as screenshot shows above), you'll need to refresh package information in order to install the package. You can do that either by issuing the command `sudo apt-get update` or by clicking "Reload" from Synaptic Package Manager from System -> Administrator.

While Microsoft Core Fonts will not get you "calibri" fonts to be precise. You can get your own fonts in any application by creating `.fonts` directory in your `home` folder and put `TTF` files of your font in this directory. Note that the directory and file name starting with the dot `.` is hidden by default in Unix-like family of operating systems, so you'll not be able to see the directory in your file manager (Nautilus, in your case) unless you select to show hidden files and folders by pressing Ctrl+H. Once you have pasted all the required font files in the directory you created, just log out and log in again and all your applications should show you the new fonts in their font lists.

Comment: Just as a warning I created a shortcut for my TTF files in my Windows directory, into my .fonts/ Ubuntu directory, everything was looking ok except "Evince" (the pdf reader) it has a problem with some Dejavu fonts which shortcut I had to delete.

Comment: As per my knowledge, you should actually keep the TTF files into your .fonts directory rather than having shortcuts (just to avoid any unexpected issue). And as far as Evince is concerned, it has something to do with the PDF file, as PDFs are based on Adobe's PostScript, which actually embeds any objects (including fonts) into the document so no matter what fonts you have, PDF will open and rendered fine. So in case you are facing this issue, it must be due to that particular PDF, and if its not, I'm afraid what could be wrong... ;-)

Comment: I wasn't clear about the problem with Dejavu fonts, the PDF are rendered perfect, the problem is with the evince UI that only show squares in the place of the letters. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/631088

Answer (score 10):

I installed via Ubuntu Software center, didn't get the fonts, etc.

I was able to remove the package with:

```
sudo apt-get remove ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

And then reinstall with:

```
sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

During which I did get the prompt asking me to agree to the EULA. Now the fonts are there. No problem.

Comment: (TAB+ ENTER) :to agree to the EULA!!  source - https://askubuntu.com/questions/16225/how-can-i-accept-the-microsoft-eula-agreement-for-ttf-mscorefonts-installer

Answer (score 7):

try this link:

> http://www.oooninja.com/2008/01/calibri-linux-vista-fonts-download.html

from http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1664796 and further links cited within.

enjoy !

Comment: download [**PowerPoint Viewer 2007**](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=048DC840-14E1-467D-8DCA-19D2A8FD7485&displaylang=en), open with 7-zip (or other) and extract *.tt? files from *.cab file and take it from there...

Answer (score 5):

Using the Ubuntu Software Center, if you neglect to agree to the EULA the first time, you'll never get another chance, even if you uninstall and reinstall.

The work-around is to open a terminal window and type

```
sudo apt-get purge ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

and once the removal is complete, type

```
sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

this will give you another chance to agree to the EULA.

Answer (score 4):

You have to install the Microsoft core fonts package *manually* via `sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer`.

I had the same problem and installed the package via the Software Center as suggested above, but the fonts were not available and actually not installed in `/usr/share/fonts/`. The reason is that the package requires user EULA agreement which can only be "clicked to agree" via the command line installer (the software center does not show the prompt).

Comment: worked for me -- I had to first uninstall the package I had installed from the Software Centre, and then reinstall from the terminal.

Comment: Just found out that Ubuntu (the 11.10 version at least) has "ubuntu-restricted-extras" package which contains the Microsoft fonts as its part.  It can be installed easily from the Ubuntu software centre.

Answer (score 1):

**Calibri Fonts:**

While logged into Ubuntu 14.04 I took four font files from my Windows 7 partition (In Windows these would be located at: C:\Windows\Fonts)and copied them to my /home/user/.fonts folder in my Linux partition.  The files I copied were:

1. calibri.ttf
2. calibrib.ttf
3. calibrii.ttf
4. calibriz.ttf

In case you don't have a .fonts folder, you can create one as follows:

In Ubuntu, in the file browser you would just go to "Home Folder", check View->Show Hidden, then File->"Create New"->Folder. Make sure you name the folder ".fonts" and not just "fonts". Then copy the .ttf files to that folder.

Here is what is looks like in terminal:

```
jim@GX270-11QPFS1:~$ cd ~
jim@GX270-11QPFS1:~$ pwd
/home/jim
jim@GX270-11QPFS1:~$ cd .fonts
jim@GX270-11QPFS1:~/.fonts$ ls
calibrib.ttf  calibrii.ttf  calibri.ttf  calibriz.ttf
jim@GX270-11QPFS1:~/.fonts$
```

[image: LibreOfficeCalibriFont]

So now I have Calibri font in Ubuntu.

Disclaimer: This technique is for educational purposes only. You may not be allowed to copy Microsoft fonts to your Ubuntu machine.

Comment: I would not advice that. In addition to be a license problem, it will impose additional problems. IMHO it is far better to use google's crosextra-carlito and crosextra-caladea fonts and make some substitutions in libreoffice/oo. See https://wiki.debian.org/SubstitutingCalibriAndCambriaFonts for the complete details.

Answer (score 0):

Search for Microsoft Fonts in the **Ubuntu Software Centre**. Find and install Installer for Microsoft TrueType Core Fonts.

[image: Installer for Microsoft TrueType Core Fonts in Ubuntu Software centre]

Answer (score 0):

since the 2020s there are more [metric-compatible fonts](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Metric-compatible_fonts) available to the Microsoft fonts. Not only to the old classics, but also to Calibri and Cambria - namely [Carlito](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Carlito) and [Caladea](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Caladea).

```
apt install fonts-croscore fonts-crosextra-carlito fonts-crosextra-caladea
```

A Word/Writer document will render properly with those installed in any [debian based](https://wiki.debian.org/SubstitutingCalibriAndCambriaFonts) distribution.