# TimesNewRoman in LibreOffice

Tags: fonts, libreoffice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LibreOffice missing certain Microsoft fonts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34077/libreoffice-missing-certain-microsoft-fonts)

I'm using ubuntu 12.04 32bit. And i need to type texts in Times New Roman. Any ideas how to install TimesNewRoman in LibreOffice Writer?

Answer (score 25):

Open up terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install msttcorefonts
```

For more help please visit [this site.](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-install-microsoft-core-fonts-in-ubuntu-linux/)

Answer (score 7):

Open **Ubuntu Software Center** and search for MS fonts.

Install Microsoft Truetype Core fonts.

[image: Ubuntu Software Center]

Hope this helps