# Installation of fonts in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I usually preferred some fonts which are not available in Ubuntu 14.04 viz. Times New Roman, Arial etc. How these fonts can be installed in Ubuntu 14.04 environment ?

Comment: Not a duplicate: this question is specifically about Microsoft fonts.

Comment: fonts are fonts @AndreaCorbellini if that dupe does not give a method to install MS fonts it should have. Whatever the font tossing them in .font is the easiest method :D

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini The issue of MS fonts has also been dealt with in the question about [Libreoffice is missing Microsoft fonts](http://askubuntu.com/questions/34077/libreoffice-missing-certain-microsoft-fonts)

Answer (score 10):

**Method 1)** Open Ubuntu Software Center and search for "ttf-mscorefonts-installer". This will install Microsoft's core fonts.

(Note: downloading ttf-mscorefonts-installer from ubuntu download centre,does not properly install the fonts because Microsoft's license is not accepted) so it can be install only from the terminal)

```
sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

then accept the Microsoft's license using tab key in a graphical interface during install.

After installing the font package you will need to update the shared font directories with the following command in a terminal shell.

```
sudo fc-cache -f -v
```

[*ttf-mscorefonts-installer*  is included in **Ubuntu-restricted-extras** and the common practice is to install them together with video codecs, flash,etc. `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`]

**Method 2)** Create a directory into your home folder, and name it ".fonts". In this folder you can copy all fonts from Windows (C:\WINDOWS\Fonts).

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the location of the downloaded fonts, then make sure they're unzipped (if they were in a compressed folder). After that, double click one and a window with a preview of the font will appear. There should be an "Install" button in the upper right corner. Click it to install the font.