# Can't access truetype fonts on Libreoffice

Tags: libreoffice

In libreoffice I can't get arial or times new roman I have installed microsoft core fonts it may be a permissions issue  Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Did you install the fonts with: sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer ? And are you sure that the install was successful?

Comment: I think so  ttf-mscorefonts-installer is already the newest version.

Comment: I tried to copy a ttf file to the truetype font directory and it said it don't have permission. I built the ubuntu pc but I don't seem to have root permissions

Comment: how do I run as root?

Comment: simply by writing sudo in front of the command. it would be sudo cp /path/of/source/font /path/of/ target/

Comment: I copied arial.ttf to downloads in my documents I can't even ls those directories  are they not actual directories ? Are they virtual?

Answer (score 5):

First check if the fonts were installed properly with

```
fc-list | grep arial
```

you should get something like:

```
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/arialbd.ttf
```

and some more lines.

If this is not the case, try reinstalling the fonts with:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

You could also try to refresh the fonts cache with:

```
sudo fc-cache -f -v
```

There is a manual way of installing the fonts, described here:
[Installation of fonts in ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/578057/installation-of-fonts-in-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: That was of extreme help I can't thank you enough I have as you would be aware limited Linux command line experience thanks again