# Issue with Terminal After Ubuntu 11.10 Install

Tags: command-line

When I try to install a program in terminal it runs for a while and then a box come up that says "Configuring ttf-mscorefonts-installer" and asks me to hit 'OK'. But I cannot hit 'OK' or make the box go away at all. If I try to close terminal it says there are still processes running. If I close it anyway I can no longer use terminal. I read on a forum that I should just delete ttf-mscorefonts-installer, but it won't let me have permission. This is just a desktop PC in my home. So, how can I fix this problem? And how can I give myself permission to delete files?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I accept the agreement for ttf-mscorefonts-installer?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16225/how-can-i-accept-the-agreement-for-ttf-mscorefonts-installer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have hit an [old bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/msttcorefonts/+bug/670629). I thought it was already fixed. Are you trying to install wine?

The solution to this i, instead of trying to click OK with mouse, just press `TAB` and then `ENTER`. It should work.

If this does not work from terminal try to do the same from synaptic.