# How Do I accept an Agreement in Terminal?

Tags: 11.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I accept the agreement in a terminal, like for ttf-mscorefonts-installer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16225/how-can-i-accept-the-agreement-in-a-terminal-like-for-ttf-mscorefonts-installer)

Well, I'm trying to install Compizconfigure settings through terminal and it worked fine but its still in the process of installation, now there is a agreement that has shown up where you can scroll down to but is there a special key I'm supposed to press to continue? I've hit enter nothing happened, to be honest I'll be waiting for a reply ASAP! until then I'll leave the installation on until someone has been able to fix it for me.

Comment: tab to the yes button and press enter key?

Comment: Agreement? What agreement? License agreements? wtf, you don't need to agree to any license to use free software, the free software licenses only cover distribution.

Comment: may be related to http://askubuntu.com/q/16225

Comment: @Arizona Can you provide a screenshot? `ccsm` does not ask you to accept a EULA, nor does any other FOSS application from the Ubuntu Software Center as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 5):

When a screen like that comes up, not just for accepting license agreements, you can use the Tab key to navigate between the different options and the Space bar to make a selection.