# How do I accept the configuration screen that pops up when installing Postfix?

Tags: software-installation, postfix

I was trying to install postfix on Ubuntu 11.10 for SMTP support... I typed

```
sudo apt-get install postfix
```

and then the installation started.

But during installation a configuration screen popped up which requested me to select an option. Now the problem is that there is no link to accept an option in the configuration screen, and as I can't select an option the installation process stalls.

If i exit the terminal and again try to re-install i get a message

```
could not get lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock -open(11. resource temporarily    unavailable)
```

---

#### Screenshots of the problem:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should be able to hit tab to move to the Ok button in the debconf window.

Comment: This question is more appropriate for http://serverfault.com/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I accept the agreement in a terminal, like for ttf-mscorefonts-installer?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16225/how-can-i-accept-the-agreement-in-a-terminal-like-for-ttf-mscorefonts-installer)

Answer (score 25):

This is similar to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16225/how-can-i-accept-the-agreement-in-a-terminal-like-for-ttf-mscorefonts-installer) for accepting an agreement in a debconf question.

<kbd>⇆ TAB</kbd> , then <kbd>return ↵</kbd> will let you continue.

Answer (score 4):

Try this command in terminal:
sudo dpkg-reconfigure postfix

This will bring up the configuration window again [where you left off]. Use the up/down arrow keys on your keyboard to select an option [where more than one option is displayed], and the left/right arrow key to choose [ok] so the next window option follows on etc. till all fields are completed by you

Comment: @iamdom....i did do that but again message appears message '2'(screenshot 2) appears on the screen

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as in the first image. <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>F12</kbd> button worked for me.