# Problem with Microsoft core fonts installer

Tags: software-center, apt, synaptic, microsoft

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I accept the agreement in a terminal, like for ttf-mscorefonts-installer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16225/how-can-i-accept-the-agreement-in-a-terminal-like-for-ttf-mscorefonts-installer)

Yes, very strange problem indeed. I installed Gnome package for a more beautifull design on my ubuntu, i don't like the looks of unity

And now, each time i run a command in the terminal, a windows called "Configuring ttf-mscorefonts-installer" appear. It ask me to accept the "end-user license agreement for microsoft software". But this windows appear in my terminal! Even tough it have an "ok" button, i can't click it. Pressing enter don't work. Pressing Y then enter, doesn't work. And if i close the terminal window, i can't run any sudo, it tells me the ressource is currently used. Pressing escape dosen't work either

Help?

EDIT:
When i close the terminal, it tells me that a program is running and closing the terminal will kill it, so i hit OK. 
When I try to run my sudo line again, after reopenning the terminal here is the message i get:
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Ressource Temporarily unavaillable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

The only way to run a command when this lock is on, is to restart the pc (I'm using a virtual Machine, so it doesn't matter). And even once the machine restarted, i still get the prompt from the microsoft font

EDIT2: The answer is in the comments....Sorry for bothering

Comment: Dang, sorry for my sutpidity. I didn't searched better, the above is the right answer. Sorry all

Comment: Don't worry about it, the search on the site is horrible anyway. :)