# Not Sure if it's Ubuntu,or my Wifi or probably both?

Tags: 12.10, networking

I'm using an Acer Aspire One Net Book
and I have Windows 7 Ultimate and Ubuntu dual booted.

- Processor: 1.66 Ghz
- 1 GB Ram
- Intel Atom
- 64 bit

I noticed that in Ubuntu, web sites don't display well. While Windows 7 does it just fine.  This happens in all browsers.  I have `ubuntu-restricted-extras` installed.

My question is..

Do I need to configure or install something to fix this?

Note: I also experienced this sort of problem on Linux Mint and Linux Chakra

More Information:
when I access somebody elses Wifi..
about..all websites display normally

Comment: What do you mean by don't display well? You should include a screenshot.

Comment: How do you include screenshots?
I'm quite new to this

Comment: You can upload the the image to an image hosting service like imgur.com and post the link of the image.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/8BNlltL.png
http://i.imgur.com/4d6QMzG.png
http://i.imgur.com/mLMS4lR.png
http://i.imgur.com/WzmuP9J.png

Some Sites don't display images or Ads
but I could still look at videos

Those things don't happen when I connect to someone else's wifi

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this might either be a rendering issue or a font issue. Windows has sub pixel rendering, or cleartype turned on by default - you can apparently activate something similar in "System > Preferences > Appearance" then fonts, then rendering.

If its missing fonts, apparently [the old MS corefonts arn't available in 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125938/upgrade-hangs-on-ttf-mscorefonts-installer) (I have no idea about mint or chakra). Since you have a windows 7 install, you could get a copy of those fonts and install them manually - you will need to copy the fonts into `/usr/local/share/fonts/truetype` (using sudo) then run `sudo fc-cache -f -v` - the ubuntu wiki has [more complete instructions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Fonts)

Its probably not a wifi problem unless pages are broken halfway.

Comment: sorry..
but that's not it

Comment: I'm not good in explaing but the issue is actually websites don't display well.Meaning their images,thumbnails,and some advertisements.They don't display.And some websites automatically goes to its TEXT form.But on Windows 7 it all displays just fine.