# Upgrade to 15.10 hangs at libxfce4ui-1-0

Tags: upgrade

Last night I attempted to upgrade from 15.04 to 15.10.  Everything went fine until the installer got to the `Installing the upgrades` step, where it hangs (stops progress) at `Installed libxfce4ui-1-0 (i386)`.  The terminal pops up, the last line of which is `Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin`.  I also have ~50% iowait on my processor, so I let it sit overnight to see if it could figure out what it needs to do.  No change.  I also don't see anything obvious going on background-wise.

Here's something from `/var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log`: `2015-10-23 08:23:50,551 WARNING no activity on terminal for 300 seconds (Installed libxfce4ui-1-0 (i386))`

Here's everything from `/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt-term.log`:

```
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-26-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-25-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-25-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-15-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-15-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
```

Those are all the clues I know how to gather at this point.  Any help will be appreciated.

The strange thing is that I didn't even know I had XFCE installed since I always use Unity.  Is there a way to tell the installer to skip this step without aborting the installation and as a consequence completely breaking my installation?  Thank you in advance.

#### Update

According to [Upgrade hangs on ttf-mscorefonts-installer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125938/upgrade-hangs-on-ttf-mscorefonts-installer), the command `ps -ejHf` can be used to gather some more clues as to what might be wrong.  For instance, `ps -ejHf | grep wily` returns:

```
root      5417  4359  2602  2602  0 Oct22 ?        00:04:22           /usr/bin/python3 /tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-e76uh732/wily --mode=server --frontend=DistUpgradeViewGtk3
root     26681  5417 26681 26681  1 Oct22 pts/1    00:11:28             /usr/bin/python3 /tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-e76uh732/wily --mode=server --frontend=DistUpgradeViewGtk3
```

That's not terribly useful, but at least it's something.

Comment: Remove the package `sudo apt-get purge libxfce4ui-1-0` and try to start the upgrade again `sudo do-release-upgrade`

Comment: @A.B., I wasn't able to finish the upgrade, but I have a functioning system without XFCE installed in case that ever becomes a problem again. I had to do `sudo dpkg --configure -a` in a terminal before `sudo apt-get purge libxfce4ui-1-0`, just so you know. Ubuntu says it's 15.10 even though I didn't finish all the steps for upgrading. Could you please post your suggestions as an answer to this question so that I can give you some street cred?

Comment: Ok, done. And please, check the last step in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said in your comments, this was the solution for you:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get purge libxfce4ui-1-0
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

If your system says, it's 15.10, everything is ok.
But you should check `/etc/apt/sources.list` for `vivid` entries and replace them with `wily`. After that execute:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```