# Can't accept EULA for ubuntu restricted extras

Tags: ubuntu-restricted-extras

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I accept the agreement in a terminal, like for ttf-mscorefonts-installer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16225/how-can-i-accept-the-agreement-in-a-terminal-like-for-ttf-mscorefonts-installer)

I can't install Ubuntu restricted extras because a Microsoft EULA pops up that I cannot respond to, so I cannot finish the total install. I have tried omitting the Microsoft bits but that doesn’t work either.