# What do I do when I see this in Terminal? Please refer to picture in description

Tags: 12.04, installation, apt, command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I accept the agreement in a terminal, like for ttf-mscorefonts-installer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16225/how-can-i-accept-the-agreement-in-a-terminal-like-for-ttf-mscorefonts-installer)

Well, I have been using the `apt-get install` command to download multiple piees of software because I'm too lazy to do it any other way, but occasionally this window comes up and I have no idea what to do. As far I have scanned, the `<Ok>` isn't even selectable!

Here's the picture:

[image]

And you've probably it's Microsoft's EULA, not Ubuntu's... so what the hell is this? Any help is appreciated.
So, what can I do?
Thanks in advance!
M

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You hit the TAB key to move around in those TUI dialog boxes. Once `<Ok>` is highlighted, hit Enter.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to install fonts that come under a non-open-source license from Microsoft. If you are fine with this, you just need to scroll down with the `TAB` on your keyboard to OK and everything will be installed and accessible properly.