# Install of wine1.5 on Ubuntu12.04 hangs at the microsoft font EULA

Tags: installation, wine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I accept the agreement in a terminal, like for ttf-mscorefonts-installer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16225/how-can-i-accept-the-agreement-in-a-terminal-like-for-ttf-mscorefonts-installer)

During the install of Wine 1.4 or 1.5, A Microsoft font package is installed, after you OK the EULA. I am unable to get a response by clicking on  or the enter key.  The installation hangs there waiting on a response. What can I do to get past this point? Noobe Thanks in advance.
DWBrayton

Comment: I've had this problem too.  Managed to fix it somehow, bit I can't replicate it now.