# Having Trouble Installing Netflix Desktop App on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, netflix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I accept the agreement in a terminal, like for ttf-mscorefonts-installer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16225/how-can-i-accept-the-agreement-in-a-terminal-like-for-ttf-mscorefonts-installer)

I added the PPA by running these commands in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ehoover/compholio
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install netflix-desktop
```

Now the Microsoft End-User License Agreement has popped up in the terminal, and I can't get it to go away and proceed with the install. What should I do?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what is says on a image hosting site (or on here)?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/rlvEH.png

Comment: try hitting the 'tab' key, if it highlights 'ok' hit enter.  See [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/224797/install-of-wine1-5-on-ubuntu12-04-hangs-at-the-microsoft-font-eula) question.