# License agreement won't go from terminal

Tags: command-line, fonts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I accept Microsoft EULA agreement for ttf-mscorefonts-installer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16225/how-can-i-accept-microsoft-eula-agreement-for-ttf-mscorefonts-installer)

After I install software via `apt-get` from the terminal I get the following:

```
TrueType core fonts for the Web EULA

END-USER LICENSE AGREEMENT FOR MICROSOFT SOFTWARE

IMPORTANT-READ CAREFULLY: This Microsoft End-User License Agreement
("EULA") is a legal agreement between you (either an individual or a
single entity) and Microsoft Corporation for the Microsoft software
accompanying this EULA, which includes computer software and may include
associated media, printed materials, and "on-line" or electronic
documentation ("SOFTWARE PRODUCT" or "SOFTWARE"). By exercising your
rights to make and use copies of the SOFTWARE PRODUCT, you agree to be
bound by the terms of this EULA. If you do not agree to the terms of
this EULA, you may not use the SOFTWARE PRODUCT.

                                 <Ok>
```

Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> does not make the message go away. How can I proceed?

Comment: Had you posted this question too: http://askubuntu.com/questions/233974/problem-with-terminal/  I had just finished answering the same thing there.