# Problem with package management after interrupting ttf-mscorefonts installer

Tags: apt, software-installation, software-center

I tried `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras` on 13.10 and it all worked well until something named `ttf-mscorefonts installer` came. It was not getting downloaded for quite a few minutes. So I quit the process.

Now I am not able to install any software, not from software center. whenever I try with something like `sudo apt-get install ****`, it shows something like:

```
$ sudo apt-get install pip
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to   correct     the problem. 
neel101@neel101-Inspiron-7520:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up update-notifier-common (0.147) ...
ttf-mscorefonts-installer: downloading http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/andale32.exe
```

and this continues for several minutes....

**EDIT**

I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> now and this came

```
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloader", line 296, in <module>
    process_download_requests()
  File "/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloader", line 234, in    process_download_requests
    dest_file = urllib.urlretrieve(files[i])[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 94, in urlretrieve
    return _urlopener.retrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 268, in retrieve
    block = fp.read(bs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 380, in read
    data = self._sock.recv(left)
KeyboardInterrupt
dpkg: error processing update-notifier-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script was interrupted
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ttf-mscorefonts-installer:
 ttf-mscorefonts-installer depends on update-notifier-common (>= 0.119ubuntu2);     however:
  Package update-notifier-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing ttf-mscorefonts-installer (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of flashplugin-installer:
 flashplugin-installer depends on update-notifier-common (>= 0.119ubuntu2); however:
  Package update-notifier-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing flashplugin-installer (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 update-notifier-common
 ttf-mscorefonts-installer
 flashplugin-installer
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I accept the Microsoft EULA agreement for ttf-mscorefonts-installer?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16225/how-can-i-accept-the-microsoft-eula-agreement-for-ttf-mscorefonts-installer) (includes information about how to accept it after rejecting it, when the package is "half installed")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below commands,

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get clean
```

It will remove all the unused packages.

OR

```
sudo dpkg -P ttf-mscorefonts-installer
sudp dpkg -P flashplugin-installer
```