# How can I add arial to the fonts used by software?

Tags: fonts

Hi people I've used Ubuntu's software centre to add Microsoft fonts (by downloading the package `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`) to Ubuntu but this doesn't seem to translate into the fonts being available for **MarvinSketch** which is actually the whole reason I added these new fonts. Plus it doesn't seem available for **LibreOffice** See I'm trying to create images that satisfy [these conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aCSDG#Drawing_in_MarvinSketch) and one of them is that the text in MarvinSketch is in Arial font. I also can't seem to get this font to be used for general things like headings and default text in other software like Google Chrome (which I'm trying to achieve by means of **Ubuntu Tweak Tool**).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced similar issue, to this one when I declined its license while installation; And another case when I disabled network to avoid downloading them. (with `wine` installation)

- `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` was marker as installed
- Where its folder was empty (do you have any font files there):

  ```
  /usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/
  ```

`ttf-mscorefonts-installer` is not a native package due to license, fonts are downloaded by a script (pre-/post-installation script)

Fixed by reinstalling it:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

Comment: It comes up with a configuring ttf-mscorefonts-installer box in the terminal, that it seems to want me to either accept or decline but I can't seem to find how I'm meant to either accept or decline it, i.e. there doesn't seem to be some key on my keyboard that I need to press to accept it.

Comment: Nvm I found it out myself; just pressed tab.

Comment: @BrentonHorne, this question covers that (just for reference), https://askubuntu.com/questions/16225/how-can-i-accept-the-microsoft-eula-agreement-for-ttf-mscorefonts-installer

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell exactly what the problem is, but you could probably find an Arial .ttf somewhere on the Internet, open it, install it, and then see if the problem persists.

Answer (score -1):

The quickest and easiest way to install the Microsoft font pack (Arial, times new roman, Comic sans, Windings) is to open terminal by press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> on keyboard  and then execute this following commands

`sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer`

Comment: I've done this through the Software centre; when I do this in terminal I get the following: `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ttf-mscorefonts-installer is already the newest version.
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  kde-l10n-engb
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 5 not to upgrade.`