# VLC won't play DVD movies

Tags: vlc, dvd

I installed VLC player on my Ubuntu 14.04 system. DVD movies won't play (no sound or picture) even though the computer tries to start the movie. What's wrong? Is the version wrong for Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: When using install ubuntu-restricted-extras as described in the answer below, to accept the EULA agreement, hit Tab, then Enter, as in [http://askubuntu.com/questions/16225/how-can-i-accept-the-microsoft-eula-agreement-for-ttf-mscorefonts-installer][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/16225/how-can-i-accept-the-microsoft-eula-agreement-for-ttf-mscorefonts-installer

Answer (score 51):

Install package *ubuntu-restricted-extras*:

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`

then run:

`sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh`

to install *libdvdcss2* library, that is not included in offical repos due to legal reasons. Now all DVD movies should play like a charm.

Comment: This also solved my problem with handbrake!

Comment: There's no install-css.sh file in that directory.

Comment: I don't have the rep to post an answer: for Ubuntu 15.10 and newer, the libdvdread4 no longer contains the install-css.sh. Instead, run: 'sudo apt-get install libdvd-pkg'. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs for more details.

Comment: This did not work for me running Ubuntu 16.04 and VLC 2.2.2

Comment: This did not work for me running 18.10.

Comment: This did not work in 20.04. `/usr/share/doc/libdvdread4` no longer exists, and the corresponding libdvdread7 doesn't contain the `install-css.sh` script.

Answer (score 28):

**Confirmed working from 16.04 - 22.04**

`sudo apt-get install libdvd-pkg`
followed by
`sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg`

Then just drag-and-drop the IFO (usually `VIDEO_TS.IFO`) into VLC window.

This also is [the official VLC solution](https://www.videolan.org/developers/libdvdcss.html).

Comment: worked for me :D

Comment: Also worked for me in 20.04.01 - would be nice if VLC had a dialog that said what the issue was, instead of just doing nothing trying to play DVDs!

Comment: This works still in 22.04. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 13):

### 15.10 and upper

Copy to terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install libdvd-pkg
```

Then install something such as:

```
sudo apt-get install pyrenamer;
sudo apt-get remove pyrenamer;
```

to run building script of libdvdcss2.

---

### 15.04 and lower

Copy to terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras;
sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh;
```

Comment: This worked for me running Ubuntu 16.04 and VLC 2.2.2

Comment: This did not work for me running 18.10.

Comment: why would you install pyrenamer and then remove it right away?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same problem with me because we open disk in wrong way, please try the following way:

http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-play-a-dvd-in-ubuntu

```
First,      insert DVD and do nothing with it (no run, no open). 
Second,     launch VLC Media Player. You can find it by searching for VLC.
Lastly,     brown to DVD files by click File and select Open Disc.
```

Comment: This did not work for me running 18.10.