# VLC 3.0.1 does not play encrypted videos

Tags: lubuntu, 17.10, vlc

On Lubuntu Artful Aardvark I have no problem with playing videos by making use of VLC 2.2.6. However I would like to use the built-in Chromecast option of the 3.0.1 version. I got it via the snap package management system.
When I try to watch a DVD I get the following message:

```
libdvdread: Encrypted DVD support unavailable.
************************************************
**                                            **
**  No css library available. See             **
**  /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/README.css     **
**  for more information.                     **
**                                            **
************************************************
```

and the video does not play.
When I go to that file it suggests to go here:
https://www.videolan.org/developers/libdvdcss.html

Here I found the following information:
Our Debian/Ubuntu repository can be accessed by adding the following lines to /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://download.videolan.org/pub/debian/stable/ /

deb-src http://download.videolan.org/pub/debian/stable/ /
```

And by running

```
wget -O - http://download.videolan.org/pub/debian/videolan-apt.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

When I did that I can see a part of the opening menu screen of the DVD, but the view is already blocked by strange looking squares. I cannot change subtitles or anything, but I can start the movie, which also has this strange appearance and it stops after a few seconds. In the terminal tons of error messages are being thrown at me (still including the above error):

```
VLC media player 3.0.1 Vetinari (revision 3.0.1-4-g14a4897)
[0000000000ff93b0] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
QApplication: invalid style override passed, ignoring it.
[0000000000ffc140] main playlist: playlist is empty
libdvdnav: Using dvdnav version 5.0.3
libdvdread: Encrypted DVD support unavailable.
************************************************
**                                            **
**  No css library available. See             **
**  /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/README.css     **
**  for more information.                     **
**                                            **
************************************************
libdvdnav: DVD Title: EN_101891
libdvdnav: DVD Serial Number: 3A686DC8___MVB__
libdvdnav: DVD Title (Alternative): 
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00fd0000. Regions: 2
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/r600_drv_video.so
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
[00007f881c001ca0] glconv_vaapi_x11 gl error: vaInitialize: unknown libva error
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/gallium_drv_video.so
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
[00007f881c001ca0] glconv_vaapi_drm gl error: vaInitialize: unknown libva error
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 1
libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with operation failed,driver_name=gallium
[00007f881c001ca0] glconv_vaapi_drm gl error: vaInitialize: operation failed
[00007f883c060630] avcodec decoder: Using G3DVL VDPAU Driver Shared Library version 1.0 for hardware decoding
[00007f883c060630] main decoder error: buffer deadlock prevented
[00007f883c037690] spudec decoder error: i_x overflowed, 739 > 720
[0000000001084af0] main audio output error: too low audio sample frequency (0)
[00007f883c045d60] main decoder error: failed to create audio output
[0000000001084af0] main audio output error: too low audio sample frequency (0)
[00007f883c054a20] main decoder error: failed to create audio output
[0000000001084af0] vlcpulse audio output error: digital pass-through stream connection failure: Not supported
[0000000001084af0] main audio output error: module not functional
[00007f883c054a20] main decoder error: failed to create audio output
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/r600_drv_video.so
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
[00007f881c0dc930] glconv_vaapi_x11 gl error: vaInitialize: unknown libva error
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/gallium_drv_video.so
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
[00007f881c0dc930] glconv_vaapi_drm gl error: vaInitialize: unknown libva error
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 1
libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with operation failed,driver_name=gallium
[00007f881c0dc930] glconv_vaapi_drm gl error: vaInitialize: operation failed
[00007f883c1a8b80] avcodec decoder: Using G3DVL VDPAU Driver Shared Library version 1.0 for hardware decoding
[mpeg2video @ 0x7f8824000da0] sequence header damaged
[mpeg2video @ 0x7f8824000da0] sequence header damaged
[mpeg2video @ 0x7f8824000da0] sequence header damaged
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Note that the answers given on the page [VLC won't play DVD movies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/505684/vlc-wont-play-dvd-movies) did not solve the encryption issue, maybe because I am running another VLC version.