# apt-get update error : W: Failed to fetch ftp://ftp.videolan.org/pub/debian/stable/./Release.gpg Could not resolve 'ftp.videolan.org'

Tags: apt, updates, update-manager, ftp

I was trying to download some media codecs a while back but I couldn't because my laptop ran out of battery(or something, don't remeber what really happened).

I tried to run `sudo apt-get update` and this is the response I got:

```
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                                
  Something wicked happened resolving 'extras.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Get:1 http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg [198 B]                          
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                    
Get:2 http://dl.google.com stable Release [1,347 B]                            
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease                       
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                              
Get:3 http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages [1,214 B]                
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg [933 B]           
Get:5 http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages [1,212 B]                 
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease                      
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release [59.7 kB]             
Hit http://download.virtualbox.org trusty InRelease                            
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease                    
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                            
Hit http://download.virtualbox.org trusty/contrib amd64 Packages               
Get:7 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg [933 B]          
Get:8 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release.gpg [933 B]        
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources [45.3 kB]        
Hit http://download.virtualbox.org trusty/contrib i386 Packages                
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_IN                         
Get:10 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release [59.7 kB]           
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources [14 B]    
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources [10.8 kB]   
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources [700 B]   
Get:14 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release [59.7 kB]         
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages [144 kB] 
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                           
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources                     
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources                       
Get:16 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages [14 B]
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources                     
Get:17 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages [48.9 kB]
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                    
Get:18 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [1,148 B]
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages              
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages                
Get:19 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages [136 kB]  
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages              
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                     
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages               
Ign http://download.virtualbox.org trusty/contrib Translation-en_IN            
Err ftp://ftp.videolan.org ./ InRelease                                        

Err ftp://ftp.videolan.org ./ Release.gpg                                      
  Could not resolve 'ftp.videolan.org'
Get:20 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages [14 B]
Get:21 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages [48.8 kB]
Ign http://download.virtualbox.org trusty/contrib Translation-en               
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages                 
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages               
Get:22 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages [1,398 B]
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources/DiffIndex                     
Get:23 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en [70.2 kB]
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                    
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex              
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex               
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en       
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en  
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en              
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                               
Get:24 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en [28.6 kB]
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en                
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Get:25 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources [121 kB]       
Get:26 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources [1,408 B]
Get:27 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources [85.1 kB]  
Get:28 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources [3,527 B]
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_IN                     
Get:29 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages [324 kB]
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                        
Get:30 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [5,820 B]
Get:31 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages [205 kB]
Get:32 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [9,373 B]
Get:33 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages [318 kB] 
Get:34 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages [5,820 B]
Get:35 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages [206 kB]
Get:36 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [9,545 B]
Get:37 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en [146 kB]
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en      
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en      
Get:38 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en [104 kB]
Get:39 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Sources [4,760 B]    
Get:40 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Sources [14 B] 
Get:41 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Sources [12.9 kB]
Get:42 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Sources [1,315 B]
Get:43 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages [6,356 B]
Get:44 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages [14 B]
Get:45 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages [16.3 kB]
Get:46 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages [943 B]
Get:47 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main i386 Packages [6,379 B]
Get:48 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages [14 B]
Get:49 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages [16.4 kB]
Get:50 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages [945 B]
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en          
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en    
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en    
Get:51 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en [13.7 kB]
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_IN                 
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_IN           
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_IN           
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_IN             
Fetched 2,346 kB in 26s (89.9 kB/s)                                            
W: Failed to fetch ftp://ftp.videolan.org/pub/debian/stable/./InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Something wicked happened resolving 'extras.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch ftp://ftp.videolan.org/pub/debian/stable/./Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'ftp.videolan.org'

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

I executed `sudo dpkg --configure -a` as requested and this was the response :

```
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.3) ...
Setting up update-notifier-common (0.154.1) ...
ttf-mscorefonts-installer: downloading http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/andale32.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloader", line 239, in process_download_requests
    dest_file = urllib.urlretrieve(files[i])[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 94, in urlretrieve
    return _urlopener.retrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 240, in retrieve
    fp = self.open(url, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 208, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 359, in open_http
    return self.http_error(url, fp, errcode, errmsg, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 372, in http_error
    result = method(url, fp, errcode, errmsg, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 665, in http_error_301
    return self.http_error_302(url, fp, errcode, errmsg, headers, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 635, in http_error_302
    data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 661, in redirect_internal
    return self.open(newurl)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 208, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 359, in open_http
    return self.http_error(url, fp, errcode, errmsg, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 372, in http_error
    result = method(url, fp, errcode, errmsg, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 635, in http_error_302
    data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 661, in redirect_internal
    return self.open(newurl)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 208, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 345, in open_http
    h.endheaders(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 969, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 829, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 791, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 772, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 553, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno -2] Name or service not known
Setting up ttf-mscorefonts-installer (3.4+nmu1ubuntu1) ...
user did not accept the mscorefonts-eula license
```

Please tell me what to do!

Comment: What was the command you were trying to run before? Try to manually remove the packages you were trying to install.

Comment: looks like something bad has happened to your DNS resolver. Can you do a `host downloads.sourceforge.net` and get the IP address of sf.net, say `216.34.181.59`? Or you can try manually putting the IP address in `/etc/hosts` for a check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reinstall mscorefonts-installer, see:

[How can I accept the Microsoft EULA agreement for ttf-mscorefonts-installer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16225/how-can-i-accept-the-microsoft-eula-agreement-for-ttf-mscorefonts-installer)

Then do `sudo dpkg --configure` again.

Comment: It says ttf-mscorefonts-installer is already the newest version. How do I reinstall it?

Comment: Use command "sudo apt-get --purge --reinstall install ttf-mscorefonts-installer" to do a reinstall.