# Something wrong with my terminal

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run this command `apt-get install mysql-server` and it sets up the packages but when it reaches a point where a password input is needed,

this is the screen i am getting

[image]

I can't even type anything.

What could be the problem?. I just installed ubuntu.

Comment: You are in `ncurses` mode of the console. You can move among fields using TAB, type the password when when the field is highlighted, and use ENTER to accept. Similar to http://askubuntu.com/questions/16225/how-can-i-accept-the-microsoft-eula-agreement-for-ttf-mscorefonts-installer

Comment: What about to typing in data?. Navigating isn't a big problem as even the up and down keys seems to work.The input part is the nightmare.

Comment: You have to use TAB until the field (where in your screenshot you see a faint green cursor) is highlighted. Then you (should) be able to type in data. Nevertheless, your terminal is strange... should look like the one in the linked posts. Which terminal are you using?

Comment: I am using putty.

Comment: In the Putty configuration, make sure that under Windows/Translation, the remote character set is set to ISO-8859-1, and "handling of line drawing characters" is set to "Use Unicode". If that doesn't help, don't type a password (you can always change it later) but TAB to the OK button and enter.

Comment: @Jos Changing from utf-8 to western Europe unicode seems to work but i still cannot enter password. I can't seem to locate `handling of line drawing characters`

Comment: False alarm,seen it.