# how to get rid of web eula notification?

Tags: apt, software-center, dpkg

whenever i install a package eula notification appears.like

```
 │ TrueType core fonts for the Web EULA                                         
 │                                                                              
 │ END-USER LICENSE AGREEMENT FOR MICROSOFT SOFTWARE                            
 │                                                                              
 │ IMPORTANT-READ CAREFULLY: This Microsoft End-User License Agreement          
 │ ("EULA") is a legal agreement between you (either an individual or a         
 │ single entity) and Microsoft Corporation for the Microsoft software          
 │ accompanying this EULA, which includes computer software and may include     
 │ associated media, printed materials, and "on-line" or electronic             
 │ documentation ("SOFTWARE PRODUCT" or "SOFTWARE"). By exercising your         
 │ rights to make and use copies of the SOFTWARE PRODUCT, you agree to be       
 │ bound by the terms of this EULA. If you do not agree to the terms of         
 │ this EULA, you may not use the SOFTWARE PRODUCT.                             
 │
```

what should i do to get rid of this ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get rid of such kind of notifications. They are bound by legal requirements. It is signing a contract for obtaining a service. You have to accept these terms if you want to use a service, otherwise don't use the service. For info about how to accept them see: [How can I accept the Microsoft EULA agreement for ttf-mscorefonts-installer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16225/how-can-i-accept-the-microsoft-eula-agreement-for-ttf-mscorefonts-installer)

From [Eula.com](http://www.eula.com.au/):

> An end user licence agreement (EULA) is a contract between one or more
>   parties based on the proprietary rights of a licensor to grant a right
>   to the licensee to use or access the subject matter of the licence.

(Most Linux designed software don't have such legal requirements, because they are open-source.)