# wine and java silent install

Tags: bash, scripts, wine, java

I am creating a bash script for my home pc. All other installs are ok but wine1.7 and oracle-java-8-installer are prompting for an 'ok' or 'accept'. How do I avoid this? I am installing from ppa's

Comment: maybe this helps: http://linux.die.net/man/1/yes and http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect

Comment: Well I don't understand a word...

Comment: my bad I was trying to say that use one of those commands, but now I have added an answer that might help.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:(Your ppa here) -y
```

Put the above thing in your script.

Comment: Adding ppa is not a problem. I am adding with -y now. Problem is with installing. All installs are with -y but prompts still occur

Comment: the prompts will still occur but the `-y` flag will continue after the 'press [enter]'

Comment: I don't think there's any way for the prompt to not appear at all.

Comment: This is the problem prompt The prompt is this http://gedakc.users.sourceforge.net/docs/kobo-ereader-with-wine/C/figures/030-mscorefonts-license-acceptance.png

Comment: ok, originally I thought it was a terminal prompt and not a ncurses prompt. Check these links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086517/eula-accept-bash-script and http://askubuntu.com/questions/16225/how-can-i-accept-the-microsoft-eula-agreement-for-ttf-mscorefonts-installer

Comment: Tried everything except the 'expect' option that I don't understand. Others don't work