# mscorefonts issue, cannot select EULA

Tags: apt, software-installation, dpkg

I ran the upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04.  Ran flawlessly until very end, and I got a pop-up which said the mscorefonts installer had not completed.  I ignored it, because I don't use any Microsoft products, and frankly prefer the Ubuntu fonts.

The pop-up keeps showing up every time I apply an upgrade or fix.  So I decided I would try to correct the problem.

First I dropped to terminal and ran:  `sudo apt purge ttf-mscorefonts-installer`  That ran without issue.  Then ran `sudo apt install ttf-mscorefonts-installer`  Now this is where the fun began.  During the install I could not accept the EULA, and had to quit the terminal with only a partial and corrupted install.

Now I can't purge because the file is corrupted, and wants me to reinstall first, but when I try to reinstall I still hang up unable to accept the EULA. 
Any advice from the Ubuntu Wizards?

Comment: ^ The answer on that question has this step `sudo dpkg-reconfigure tts-mscorefonts-installer` and that should make you able to accept the EULA. follow the steps and let us know if that works

Comment: 'Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
dpkg: error processing package ttf-mscorefonts-installer (--purge):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ttf-mscorefonts-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)'   This is what is returned.  I would really like to just

Comment: I seem to be stuck...  I can't get the corrupted fonts-installer removed, and I can't reinstall or configure it until it is un-corrupted.

Comment: use `sudo dpkg -r --ttf-mscorefonts-installer` to remove it

Comment: That returned this, did I use an incorrect switch?  *dpkg: error: unknown option --ttf-mscorefonts-installer

Type dpkg --help for help about installing and deinstalling packages [*];
Use 'apt' or 'aptitude' for user-friendly package management;
Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values;
Type dpkg --force-help for a list of forcing options;
Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;

Options marked [*] produce a lot of output - pipe it through 'less' or 'more' !*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43526/discussion-between-desert-sailor-and-anwar-shah).

Comment: This answer helps in accepting EULA http://askubuntu.com/questions/16225/how-can-i-accept-the-microsoft-eula-agreement-for-ttf-mscorefonts-installer?rq=1