# How do I accept Oracle's license agreement while installing JDK?

Tags: 18.04, java, jdk

I am trying to install Java on Ubuntu 18.04. by running:

```
sudo apt install oracle-java14-installer
```

But when I reach the part where I have to accept the license agreement there is link leading to the Oracle page, but when I click on that link it's "Page not found". I'm stuck on this page?

[image: message that i'm prompted to]

How do I accept the license agreement? I'm using [linuxprising's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~linuxuprising/+archive/ubuntu/java).

Comment: No, I'm just running the command

Comment: # deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20200203.1)]/ bionic main restricted

Comment: I installed openjdk-14-jdk on my Ubuntu 19.10 server, but I cant find the *license agreement*. Can you explan how you got it?

Comment: I just ran the command and got prompted to it in the console.

Comment: Actually i'm prompted to that window if I try to install any version now. I got really stuck with that.

Comment: For God's sake, that solved the problem! It's appreciated really.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I accept the Microsoft EULA agreement for ttf-mscorefonts-installer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16225/how-can-i-accept-the-microsoft-eula-agreement-for-ttf-mscorefonts-installer) Licenses are accepted in similar ways :)

Answer (score 6):

Press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.

When the `<Ok>` text at bottom center gets RED, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.