# How can I use Ansible to claim that I accept the Microsoft EULA agreement for ttf-mscorefonts-installer?

Tags: microsoft, ansible

[How can I accept the Microsoft EULA agreement for ttf-mscorefonts-installer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16225/how-can-i-accept-the-microsoft-eula-agreement-for-ttf-mscorefonts-installer) lists some ways to achieve this (GUI, script, puppet config).

But I am at loss how to handle `echo ttf-mscorefonts-installer msttcorefonts/accepted-mscorefonts-eula select true` in Ansible.

Simply running this command on every run of Ansible playbook seems substandard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got this problem on ***Ubuntu 20.04*** with ***Ansible 2.11*** when trying to install `ubuntu-restricted-extras` meta package that includes `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`.

With @bstabens answer and comment, I figured out how to accept msttcorefonts license agreement.

On an already installed machine, I checked which question I add to agree during `msttcorefonts` install

`debconf-show ttf-mscorefonts-installer` command gave me this output

```
* msttcorefonts/accepted-mscorefonts-eula: true
  msttcorefonts/dldir:
  msttcorefonts/baddldir:
  msttcorefonts/error-mscorefonts-eula:
* msttcorefonts/present-mscorefonts-eula:
  msttcorefonts/dlurl:
```

Saying that I've answered `true` to `msttcorefonts/accepted-mscorefonts-eula` question.

I then wrote my playbook like this :

```
---
- hosts : dev
  tasks:
    - name: prepare eula 
      debconf:
        name: ttf-mscorefonts-installer
        question: msttcorefonts/accepted-mscorefonts-eula
        vtype: boolean
        value: true

    - name: Install a list of packages
      apt:
        update_cache: yes
        state: latest
        pkg:
        - ubuntu-restricted-extras
        - ... OTHER PACKAGES HERE

  become : yes
  become_method : sudo
```

Invoked it with `ansible-playbook my_playbook.yaml --ask-become-pass` and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

With ansible:

```
- name: prepare eula 
  debconf:
    name: ttf-mscorefonts-installer
    question: msttcorefonts/accepted-mscorefonts-eula
    value: true
```

These things get configured with debconf, and you can see all options with

> debconf-show **package**

Of course, then you'll have to install it at least once manually. Please note, debconf does not install the package, it simply prepares debconf for it.

Comment: "Of course, then you'll have to install it at least once manually." then how it is solving fact that I want to do it with Ansible?

Comment: It solves it for every following installation. Besides, you're free to just google in advance what debconf questions that given package wants to have set so you don't have to install it.