# Cannot remove update

Tags: apt

I recently attempted to install a required update which was needed by software I installed on PlayOnLinux, however the update never installed.  The system would infinitely hang up on the install and I would be forced to kill the install process (not ideal I know).

Now the system continues to show the software (ttf-mscorefonts-installer) as an update in the Discover Center on Kubuntu. I am not having success removing the update via Discover or at the command line. Also notice - it shows the page is 0 B in size. I included a screenshot of the update in Discover.

[image]

Here is my attempt to remove the update from the terminqal:

```
scott@scott-ZenBook:~$ sudo apt remove ttf-mscorefonts-installer
[sudo] password for scott: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libllvm10 python3-debconf update-notifier-common
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  ttf-mscorefonts-installer
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
dpkg: error processing package ttf-mscorefonts-installer (--remove):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ttf-mscorefonts-installer
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

It says I should try to reinstall it before uninstalling.  Well, I can't.  The software consistently locks up the install process.  Is there a way to remove this once and for all?

Comment: The `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` package has a EULA that you must accept as part of the install process. That's why it runs forever -- it's awaiting your input. See [How can I accept the Microsoft EULA agreement for ttf-mscorefonts-installer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16225/how-can-i-accept-the-microsoft-eula-agreement-for-ttf-mscorefonts-installer)

Comment: I have tried multiple times to accept the EULA, but it won’t let me. No key inputs or mouse inputs accept the EULA. When I try to install via the software center, it asks me to read and accept the EULA - but is is blank and there is no “accept” or “ok” option. When I try via the console, I can scroll through the EULA, but cannot accept it.