# installing Ms core fonts stalled at 38% so now I'm stuck

Tags: dual-boot, libreoffice, fonts

I was installing MS core fonts and all went well until 38% when it stopped I waited hours and nothing more. so now I'm stuck. I'm running Unbuntu 20.04.3 and the Libre office that comes with it. I need these fonts for School, they insist that you use MS fonts Times New Roman, Arial, which I use, and another or 2 for all papers.
Yes I accepted the license agreement.
I Tried the suggested reinstall and got this:

```
jeff@jeff-Aspire-E5-571:~$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall ttf-mscorefonts-installer
[sudo] password for jeff: 
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

Comment: You can interrupt the apt operation by <Ctrl>+<C>. Then reinstall the MS fonts package by `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ttf-mscorefonts-installer` followed by `sudo apt-get install -f`.

Comment: Did you accept the license?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I accept the Microsoft EULA agreement for ttf-mscorefonts-installer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16225/how-can-i-accept-the-microsoft-eula-agreement-for-ttf-mscorefonts-installer)

Answer (score 0):

As a newbee in Linux world, I was stuck in the same spot. After some search, I have found this thread, however, root cause was need to Accept the licence to continue with font installation.

Following thread helped me resolve blocking issue, but in short you need to switch focus inside of the window to the Licence prompt by pressing TAB, and to confirm the choice by pressing SPACE or ENTER:
[How can I accept the Microsoft EULA agreement for ttf-mscorefonts-installer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16225/how-can-i-accept-the-microsoft-eula-agreement-for-ttf-mscorefonts-installer)