# UUCP Install stalls

Tags: software-installation

Box is Ubuntu 22.0.4.1, trying to install UUCP with the command line: sudo apt install uucp  After a few seconds, the terminal screen becomes purple outlined with "Package configuration" at the top left. The a line down, top middle red letters on a gray background "Postfix Configuration" and "Please select the mail server configuration style that best meets your need."  Then "No configuration", "Internet site", etc. with "" at the bottom.

The thing is, nothing seems to be accepted as input, I can hit the return key, highlight text, nothing.  How do I make the selection and/or get passed this screen?

Comment: You should be able to navigate the ncurses screen with arrow and tab keys, same as [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/16228/178692)

Comment: Yes!  Thank you.